# laravel - Can I create controller from a controller?

Tags: laravel

I've a controller to create a controller. SiteController is an example.

```
public function createSiteController() {
    $controller_name = "SiteController";
    Artisan::call("make:controller",
        [
            "name"=>$controller_name
        ]);
}
```

It gives me following error.

> file_put_contents(/Volumes/Data/www/cms/app/Http/Controllers/SiteController.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tried to set `chmod("/Volumes/Data/www/cms/app/Http/Controllers", 0777)`, but it is not permitted.

Edit: Of course, i don't want to use 0777. It was just an example. I would never use that. I am just saying

Comment: why you even need to do that? It smells like completely odd and broken design at best

Comment: How can you say that? I am building a CMS where you can dynamically create controller and model. I am able to do that with the help of terminal command. Everyone has own requirement.  It's okay if you don't want to answer.

Comment: While indeed everybody has there reason to do certain stuff, please do reconsider this, starting with your permission strategy, it is never a good idea to "just set a file's permission to 777". Why do you want to create a controller, how do you plan on editing the controllers content?

Comment: Of course, i don't want to use 0777. It was just an example. I would never use that. I am just saying. Is there any way to create controller from a controller. I

Comment: in first place, you do not understand what your problem is. It got **nothing** in common with controller nor creating of such from it. It's matter of server configuration, and mismatch between user owning the www folder (or cms) subfolder and user which is used to run your scripts (usually www-data)

Comment: 4+5=9 and 6+3=9. Why this example? Every problem has multiple ways to solve it.  Thinking that you are a genius is good, but thinking everyone is stupid is not ok I guess.   I have clearly written what's my problem is. Anyway.  If anyone is looking for answer: first make a copy to temp folder and move it to your controller folder using copy command. It works.

Comment: Seems you got problems receiving criticism

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a problem to create a controller using a controller. I was unable to do it using artisian command.

Why I need that?
I've created an artisian command. something like this. (php artisian cms:controller controllerName)

It should be extended to **BaseAdminController** rather than default **Controller**. So I've made a template to create a custom controller. Just like laravel itself does.

I've fixed this problem using below steps.
* First you need to make a new file in a temp folder.
* Manipulate/Change whatever you want in that file. 
* and copy that file (Controller in my case) to your Controller folder using **copy** command.